# Joining based on email within strings on AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, join, presto, email-validation, amazon-athena

I have two S3 buckets that I am looking to join on Athena. In the first bucket, I have an email address in a CSV file with an email column.

```
sample@email.com
```

In the other bucket, I have a JSON file with nested email addresses used by the client. The way this has been set up in Glue means the data looks like this:

```
[sample@email.com;email@sample.com;com@email.sample]
```

I am trying the join the data by finding the email from the first bucket inside of the string from the second bucket. I have tried:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(lower("emailaddress"), lower("emails"))
```

with no success, I have also tried:

```
select "source".*, "target".*
FROM "source"
inner join "target"
on "membername" = "first_name"
and "memberlastname" = "last_name"
and '%'||lower("emailaddress")||'%' like lower("emails")
```

With no success. I am doing something wrong and it is evading me where I am making this error.

Comment: Can't you just use `WHERE emails LIKE '%' || LOWER(emailaddress) || '%'`? I think you had it the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to reverse your `like` arguments:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, email) AS (
    VALUES (1,'sample@email.com'),
    (2,'non-present@email.com')
),
dataset2 (emails) as (
    VALUES ('[sample@email.com;email@sample.com;com@email.sample]')
)

-- query
SELECT *
FROM dataset
INNER JOIN dataset2 on 
   lower(emails) like '%' || lower(email) || '%'
```

Output:

| id | email | emails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sample@email.com | [sample@email.com;email@sample.com;com@email.sample] |